# Multiple convolutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

Let $\phi(x)=1$ on [0,1] and 0 anywhere else. Is there a was to say what the support of the n-times convolution of phi with itself, that I wann to denote by $B_n$, is? In especially is it possible to find $h_n$ such that $\phi (x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} h_n \phi(2x-n)$

Comment: After the first convolution, the support will be $[0,2]$. After the next one $[0,3]$, and so on and so on. As for finding $h_n$, you can look at [deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution), though I think the zeros in the spectrum might make things difficult.